# Get application external sd home directory

Tags: java, android, sd-card

This post is ALL edited so...

I want to save a bitmap from `@drawable` in sdcard `(/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/app_package/files/)`. If i try `ContextWrapper.getFilesDirectory()` it will return `"/data/data/app_package/files/"`. I want to get "/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/app_package/files/". Is there any method to return it?

Thanks in advance,
Mateiaru

Comment: Please refine your question. I cannot see how storing a bitmap on the SD card will solve the problem that _the bitmap isn't the phone's size_ (and you should also clarify what you mean by _that_).

Comment: @user2156778 Read my post and make this post to accept if its useful for your problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save bitmap in external storage.

First get the bitmap of drawable then save it into SD card.

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourBitmap);
```

Saving it SD card.

```
public void saveImageToExternalStorage(Bitmap image) {
    //image=scaleCenterCrop(image,200,200);
    String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data/";
    try
    {
        File dir = new File(fullPath);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
        }
        OutputStream fOut = null;
        File file = new File(fullPath, "photo.png");

        if(file.exists())
            file.delete();

        file.createNewFile();
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        // 100 means no compression, the lower you go, the stronger the compression
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("saveToExternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To store a bitmap from drawable directry to external storage .. but i dont know how it will help you

```
        File f=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"1.jpg");
        InputStream inputStream =       getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.the drawable you want to save);
        OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(f);
        byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while((len=inputStream.read(buf))>0)
        out.write(buf,0,len);
        out.close();
        inputStream.close();
```

Comment: OMG the answer came in 1 min (I counted).

Comment: @user2156778 mark as answered, if this answers your question, and upvote if the answer is great too!